# Geometry nodes weird shadow

Tags: geometry-nodes, shadows

I created a setup to generate simple tents using geometry nodes. The problem is that if I set "shade smooth" something weird happens with the shadows (regardless of wether I use cycles or eevee).

[image: With shade smooth on]
[image: And with shade smooth off]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have build your model using squashed cubes. This is how cubes looks like, then you try to smooth them:

[image]

Replace cubes by **Mesh Primitives** → **Grid**